# Referencing/Calculating Previous columns in a DataFrame in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm setting up my first analysis in Python and Pandas (newbie in both), and have a few questions/issues on how to set this up properly.

Essentially, I am trying to look at user behavior in a time-series, but I have more users than days, so I am attempting to look monthly.  I've built the `DataFrame` this way:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'ID':range(100)})
df2['Day1'] = random.sample(xrange(1000), 100)
df2['Day2'] = random.sample(xrange(1000), 100)
df2['Day3'] = random.sample(xrange(1000), 100)
```

I've tried to add an index to the 'ID' column several ways, but 1) am not sure I need it and 2) none of my methods will take.  Here is what I have tried:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'ID':range(100)}, index_col='ID')
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'ID':range(100)}, index_col=0)
df2.index(0)
df2.index('ID')
df2.reindex(index='ID')
df2.reindex(index=0)
```

The end output of what I am trying to get to create a new dataframe which will show whether the Day2 values is 95% less than Day 1, whether Day 3 is 95% less than Day 2 - onward (imagine I had a `DataFrame` of 100 columns).  The output I would look might look like this:

```
ID   Day2   Day3
1    NaN    1
2    NaN    NaN
3    NaN    NaN
4    1      NaN
```

I believe the appropriate way to determine this is run a for loop with something like this:

```
for i in df2:
  if (Day2-Day1)/Day1 < .95:
    print 1
```

However, I'm not sure how I can reference the columns in my function, nor how I can make this function flexible to include all columns in the `DataFrame`.  How should I reference the columns for this function?

How should I reference the columns for this function?

Answer (score 1):

There's probably an easier way to do this using a panel, but I don't have any experience with time series yet.  This is how I would accomplish what you want using DataFrames:

First make a dummy `DataFrame`:

```
In [231]: df2 = DataFrame(np.random.rand(100,3)*100, columns=['Day1','Day2','Day3'])

In [232]: df2.head()
Out[232]:
        Day1       Day2       Day3
0  93.347819  92.866771  91.381466
1   7.819967  26.415094  79.477087
2  98.792627  92.940538  83.774519
3  64.182073  22.563504  15.631763
4  82.460359  89.743872  87.511540
```

Now, make a new `DataFrame` by dropping the first column of `df2`

```
In [233]: df3 = df2.ix[:,1:]

In [234]: df3.head()
Out[234]:
        Day2       Day3
0  92.866771  91.381466
1  26.415094  79.477087
2  92.940538  83.774519
3  22.563504  15.631763
4  89.743872  87.511540
```

The ix notation allows you to slice columns.  It can be confusing at first, but it reads in English as: "Take all of the rows and only the columns from 1 to the end".

At this point both `DataFrames` have the same index.  You don't need to create your own 'ID' unless you need it for something else.  Pandas will automatically index each `DataFrames` for you.  This aligns the `DataFrames` for all sorts of operations.  It does the same thing with the columns.  It will line up the `DataFrames` by the column names and perform whatever operations you want.  Since you want to divide by the 'next' day, we have to change the columns in `df3`:

```
In [235]: df3.columns = df2.columns[:-1]

In [236]: df3.head()
Out[236]:
        Day1       Day2
0  92.866771  91.381466
1  26.415094  79.477087
2  92.940538  83.774519
3  22.563504  15.631763
4  89.743872  87.511540
```

Now we have renamed the columns so they will align the way we want.  Performing the division calculation is easy as Pandas will do all the alignment.  No loops necessary!

```
In [244]: df4 = (df2/df3 < .95)

In [245]: df4.head()
Out[245]:
    Day1   Day2   Day3
0  False  False  False
1   True   True  False
2  False  False  False
3  False  False  False
4   True  False  False
```

Answer (score 0):

Since pandas in it's current form assumes time series data are arranged with time in the index, not the columns, transposing the DataFrame, at least temporarily, will enable the use of many built-in methods, such as  `shift`/`diff`/`pct_change`/etc.

```
In [78]: df = DataFrame(np.random.rand(100, 3) * 100,
                        columns=['Day1', 'Day2', 'Day3'])

In [79]: df.head()
Out[79]: 
        Day1       Day2       Day3
0  27.113276   0.827977  37.059887
1  48.817798  19.335033  12.476411
2  27.001015  18.147742  33.094676
3  38.428321  95.609824  72.395564
4  63.626472  36.207677   1.328216

In [80]: dft = df.T

In [82]: dft.ix[:, :5]
Out[82]: 
              0          1          2          3          4          5
Day1  27.113276  48.817798  27.001015  38.428321  63.626472  25.900132
Day2   0.827977  19.335033  18.147742  95.609824  36.207677   0.191767
Day3  37.059887  12.476411  33.094676  72.395564   1.328216  37.011027

In [89]: dft.pct_change().ix[:, :5]
Out[89]: 
              0         1         2         3         4           5
Day1        NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN         NaN
Day2  -0.969462 -0.603935 -0.327887  1.488004 -0.430934   -0.992596
Day3  43.759576 -0.354725  0.823625 -0.242802 -0.963317  191.999688

In [94]: chg = (dft.pct_change().dropna() < .95).T.astype(int)

In [95]: chg.head()
Out[95]: 
   Day2  Day3
0     1     0
1     1     1
2     1     1
3     0     1
4     1     1
```